# ffmpeg Converting files in place

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg on a daily basis to convert multiple video files to various other formats. Because of this I can't be moving ffmpeg and multiple batch files all over the place.

I have the folder `C:\ffmpeg` which contains `ffmpeg.exe` and all my different batch file converters for the different formats. I then have a shortcut on the desktop to the batch file which I can drag and drop video files onto to convert them.

As it stands, I use this to convert the video files in place.

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
"%~dp0\ffmpeg.exe" -i %%A -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac %%A_Converted.mp4
)
```

Dragging and dropping the video file `example.avi` from the folder `C:\Users\User\Documents\Folder` results in the file `example.avi_Converted.mp4` being created in the same location (perfect!).

I am wanting to remove the original file type, `.avi` from the new file name - so the output file is `example_Converted.mp4`. I can do this using `~n`, shown in the following code sample, although the new file then gets created in `C:\ffmpeg` instead of in `C:\Users\User\Documents\Folder`.

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
"%~dp0\ffmpeg.exe" -i %%A -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac "%%~nA_Converted.mp4"
)
```

Is there a way to do this so that the output file is created is the same place as the input file?

Comment: Try with `"%%~dpnA_Converted.mp4"`

Comment: @MCND That is perfect, thank you! I had tried `%~dp0\%%~nA_Converted.mp4` which was along the right lines, but didn't work

Comment: ...and instead of `-i %%A` you should use `-i "%%~A"`...

Comment: The `dpn` are modifiers or the variables. `%~dp0` is the drive and path of the batch file (the *variable* is `%0`), while `%%~dpnA` are the drive, path and file name of the file being iterated (`%%A`).

Comment: Technically you should change your `"%~dp0\ffmpeg.exe"` to `"%~dp0ffmpeg.exe"` as `%~dp0` already carries a trailing backslash.